# Cannot read property React function component issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having this issue with a function component that it's giving me:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

These are the parts that implements the 'name' input:

```
const initialState = { user: { name: '', email: '' }, list: []}
...
export default (props) => 
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const user = state.user;
...
  function handleChange (event){
          setState({...state.user, 
                    [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }  
  <TextField
        className="form-control"
        name="name"
        placeholder="Digite o nome..."
        type="text"
        value={state.user.name}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        required={true}
    />
```

I know I could easly do this with a Class Component, but i would like to do with a functional one, is it possible?

Comment: You're not spreading deep enough into the state object. It should be: `setState({...state, user: {...state.user, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}})`

Comment: Try useCallback if you like using hooks or convert the handleChange into an arrow function.

Comment: @lawrence-witt tried, but didn't work. Same error...

Comment: I found out what was going on. I tried to use the useState twice in the same component, and the fisrt useState will always be lost when the second one is called. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

I think the issue is one, or both, of the following, both in the `handleChange` callback function.

1. You don't shallow copy the nested state correctly. `{...state.user` spreads the user values up a level to the root of the state object.
2. The `onChange` event has been nullified by the time the state update is processed.

## Solution

1. `useState` state updater doesn't merge state updates, you need to shallow copy *all* parts of state that are being updated, and in this case that is `state` and `state.user`. I suggest also using a functional state update since you ***are*** updating from the previous state.
2. The `onChange` event is possibly nullified so you should destructure/save the input's `name` and `value` properties *before* enqueueing the state update.

Code:

```
function handleChange(event) {
  const { name, value } = event.target; // <-- save name and value
  setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,        // <-- shallow copy previous state
    user: {
      ...prevState.user, // <-- shallow copy previous state.user
      [name]: value,     // update property
    },
  }));
}
```

Comment: I'm not following your code: I need to set two states?

Comment: @RafaelPáduaDelCorona No, according to your code snippet there's still only the one single `state` state. What part of my solution is tripping you up? I don't mind going into greater detail where it helps you.

Comment: @RafaelPáduaDelCorona Do you still have question(s)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You say I need to shallow copy all parts of the state, but when I call the setState function aren't I already accessing all of these parts?

Comment: @RafaelPáduaDelCorona Accessing and shallow copying are *not* the same thing. You are accessing, but you also still need to shallow copy into a new object reference any state that you are updating. For the `useState` hook updater function this also means the root state object since it doesn't merge in updates. You are updating `state.user.<field>`, so you must shallow copy `state`, and then shallow copy `state.user`

Comment: Oh I see. So actually the react never changes the origial state. It just access and shallow copies it into a new object